# Doubt between deseasonalized ARIMA and SARIMA

Tags: arima, seasonality, acf-pacf

I'm new in time series analysis and I'm currently working with a time series that has a trend and a marked seasonalization. As a result, I've detrended and deseasonalized the series before plotting the ACF and PACF. Then, after getting the plots I have two questions:

Do I have to model the series as an ARIMA with two orders of integration(one for the detrend and another for the deseasonalization, getting an ARIMA(1,2,1)) or should I model the series as a SARIMA(1,1,1)(0,1,0)?

If after detrending and deseasonalizing I get ACF and PACF that have a significant correlation at lag=12, Do I have to deseasonalize the data again (getting a hypothetical ARIMA(1,3,1)) or model the series as a SARIMA(1,1,1)(0,2,0)?

I'm aware that I should choose the most parsimonious model, but I don't know which would be in these cases.

Comment: Be careful with differencing the data as you can quickly face the problems of overdifferencing. E.g. if you have a deterministic trend, differencing is not the answer.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for the caveat, I'll keep that in mind.